# InfluxDB-Python: Unable to query by Tag value

Tags: python, influxdb, influxdb-python

I have a problem regarding queries in InfluxDB with python.

I have the following simple code:

```
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

client = InfluxDBClient(host='localhost', port=8086)



client.create_database('pyexample')

databases= client.get_list_database()

client.switch_database('pyexample')


json_body = [
    {
        "measurement": "brushEvents",
        "tags": {
            "user": "1",
            "brushId": "6c89f539-71c6-490d-a28d-6c5d84c0ee2f"
        },
        "time": "2018-03-28T8:01:00Z",
        "fields": {
            "duration": 127
        },
        "measurement": "brushEvents",
        "tags": {
            "user": "Carol",
            "brushId": "6c89f539-71c6-490d-a28d-6c5d84c0ee2r"
        },
        "time": "2018-03-28T8:01:00Z",
        "fields": {
            "duration": 129
        },
        "measurement": "brushEvents",
        "tags": {
            "user": "Evi",
            "brushId": "6c89f539-71c6-490d-a28d-6c5d84c0ee2e"
        },
        "time": "2018-03-28T8:01:00Z",
        "fields": {
            "duration": 132
        }
    }
    
]
client.write_points(json_body)

query = client.query('SELECT * FROM "brushEvents" WHERE "user"="Carol" ')


print(query)
```

I am trying to get only the user Carol with all fields, but with the query above, I am only receiving an empty ResultSet({}).

What I am doing wrong? I even tried it with single quotes.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made two mistakes in your code:

1. Your json body is wrong you need to put each measurement in {} and separate them with ,

```
json_body = [
    {
        "measurement": "brushEvents",
        "tags": {
            "user": "1",
            "brushId": "6c89f539-71c6-490d-a28d-6c5d84c0ee2f"
        },
        "time": "2018-03-28T8:01:00Z",
        "fields": {
            "duration": 127
        }
    },
    {
        "measurement": "brushEvents",
        "tags": {
            "user": "Carol",
            "brushId": "6c89f539-71c6-490d-a28d-6c5d84c0ee2r"
        },
        "time": "2018-03-28T8:01:00Z",
        "fields": {
            "duration": 129
        }
    },
    {    
        "measurement": "brushEvents",
        "tags": {
            "user": "Evi",
            "brushId": "6c89f539-71c6-490d-a28d-6c5d84c0ee2e"
        },
        "time": "2018-03-28T8:01:00Z",
        "fields": {
            "duration": 132
        }
    }

]
```

2. Your tag value has to be in single quotes:

```
query = client.query('''SELECT * FROM "brushEvents" WHERE "user"='Carol' ''')
```

Another option is to use parameter binding which is the preferred method:

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM "brushEvents" WHERE user=$user'
bind_params = {'user': 'Carol'}
result = client.query(query, bind_params=bind_params)
```